# AGM Angular: Why blinking markers in Google Maps?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-markers

I'm implementing real time tracking of aircraft. I have developed an array like this:

> > listAircraft = [] 
> >     listAircraft[ID] = { lat: xx, lng: yy}

When a new plane arrives, I add to the aircraft list.

In the HTML I draw an aircraft marker like this:

```
<agm-map class="map" [zoom]="zoom" [latitude]="mapCenter.lat" [longitude]="mapCenter.lng" [streetViewControl]="false" [mapTypeControl]="false" (mapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
        <agm-marker  *ngFor="let aircraft of listAircraft | keyvalue" [latitude]="aircraft.value.lat" [longitude]="aircraft.value.lng" 
               [iconUrl]="aircraft.value.plane" >
            <agm-info-window *ngIf="aircraft.value.plane" [disableAutoPan]="true" [isOpen]="true">
                {{aircraft.value.regn}} <br/>
                {{aircraft.value.last_alt}}, {{aircraft.value.gndspd}}
            </agm-info-window>
        </agm-marker>
 </agm-map>
```

Issue:
When a new plane arrives,in the UI all aircraft markers blinking.

Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14FiG8yjGI77jCHaGMdshhgH_9h6WwM5Q/view
In this link you can see a short video about the issue.

Or could be in app: http://krdu.1200.aero

Comment: Adding a `trackBy` function to your `ngFor` will fix it. It happens because whenever you are adding a new plane to the array, Angular is refreshing the array. If you provide it a `trackBy` function, then Angular will only refresh with the delta i.e. new/deleted element. https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor

Comment: @ashish.gd thank you! you save my day! I just wrote a code with track by and my bug with info window has gone! Wish you have a good day too.